# AAD B2c primary key

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm using Blazor webassembly with Azure ADB2C. A typical task is to retrieve only those records for the logged in user.  Which field from AzureB2C is the best practice to use as the authorized user's primary key?

I assumed that using the object ID which is a guid and created by Azure ADB2C would be the correct unique field. However I also see examples on the internet using either the user's email and/or user's name.

I plan on using this field as as a unique field in database tables for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per documentation, Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) uses userprincipalname or objectID for queries

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

You can apply filters to Microsoft Graph calls but generally the objectID is immutable and is the primary identifier that I've seen with enterprise applications/services.